# How can I obtain the optimal bandwidth on 2D gaussian KDE?

Tags: python, kde-plasma, astronomy

So, my first time in here asking for help.

I'm stuck with a statiscal problem. I'm creating 2D density maps for my work, using R(radius) and $\theta$ (angle) as coordinates and i'm using this python function {scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(values,BW)} to create a density map.

My problem is, how can i calculate the best bandwidth to my data? Is there some function/library on python?

-I know that GridSearchCV can estimate the bandwidth for univariate, but i have two variables =(.

thanks for the help and sorry for bad english.

Comment: According to the docs you can use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.set_bandwidth.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.set_bandwidth to define a method. The methods are also directly callable from the gaussian_kde object, e.g. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.scotts_factor.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.scotts_factor. The docs refer to "D.W. Scott, “Multivariate Density Estimation: Theory, Practice, and Visualization”, John Wiley & Sons, New York, Chicester, 1992." for the multivariate case.

Comment: Please also note, that the bandwidth selection is not trivial and requires some investigation, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#Bandwidth_selection to get some ideas which you can implement.

Comment: Another library you could use is sklearn, see the following example https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_digits_kde_sampling.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neighbors-plot-digits-kde-sampling-py and the documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html#kernel-density-estimation and https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity